# How to add and commit with a message only one file?

Tags: javascript, html, git, version-control

I'm working with an index, script and style files for my project, when I finished some modifications I want to add and commit with a message to each file, so I can track the changes that I made in that specifically file, how can I do that? (instead of doing git add -> git commit -m -> git add -> git commit -m -> ...)

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose I have a directory "Project". inside this I have 3 files like index.html style.css and app.js

I made some changes on each files. now I want to do separate commits for individual file. so ill do and follow this steps :

```
1) Open terminal / git bash
2) Navigate on Project Directory using cd command.
3) git init
4) git add index.html
5) git commit -m "commit message for index.html"
6) git add style.css
7) git commit -m "commit message for style.css"
8) git add app.js
9) git commit -m "commit message for app.js"
10) git remote add remote_name remote_url
11) git push remote_name branch_name
```

I hope my answer will solve your problem and let me know if your problem solved.

Note:- git add . command add all files but we don't want this that's why we are using git add filename.extension for separate file.

Comment: Hi, well, that's the procedure that I follow, I was asking if there was a way to combine the 4-5 steps, just one step to add and commit for that file

Answer (score 0):

git commit 'filename1' -m "comment1" 'filename2' -m "comment2"...etc

Answer (score 0):

idk if you had the same issue as me but what I did is add a comment to each of my files "// comment for git commit change" and then redid the files one by one. what i had done was accidentally git commit -am which committed the same message to all my files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).